# Paragraph inside Anchor cannot be formated

Tags: html, css, paragraph, text-formatting

while working i messed HTML because i did not knew that `<p>` tag within `<a>` tag does not get formated .

Like if i had :

```
<a>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, </p>
</a>
```

where `<a>` parent width is `200px;` text goes through `200px;` instead of putting New Lines to fit the text inside .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to make

```
a {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: just checked the following code: <a style="display: block; width: 200px;">
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, </p>
</a> - it's working

Comment: @Burimi: your issue had to do with [markup validity](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16957893/1081234)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the display: block; to the a element fixes it. The a tag is an inline element by default. It was not meant to hold other elements and so the width property does not affect it. Using CSS to make it display like a block element should make properties like width work correctly. I've got a working demo on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gtNYx/).

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is just missing the compulsory anchor `href` attribute. The following would render properly:

```
<a href="#">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text... ever since the 1500s, </p>
</a>
```

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/6M3dX/)